# spring3 file upload and save - extra null characters at the end

Tags: spring

I am trying to upload a file to my local spring3 web application and saving the file locally. The following is the code snippet:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveForm(@ModelAttribute("fileUploadForm") FileUploadForm form, BindingResult result) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = form.getFile().getInputStream();
        logger.debug("uploadfile: "+form.getFile());
        String fileName = form.getFile().getOriginalFilename();
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFileDir+"\\"+fileName);
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytes);          
        }

        outputStream.close();

        return "fileUploadSuccess";     
    }
```

The jsp file doing the file upload is:

```
<form:form method="post" action="uploadFile" modelAttribute="fileUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>        
        <td><input name="file" type="file" /></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="label.upload"/>" name="submit" />
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form:form>
```

Now after opening both the uploaded file and the saved file, I can see that the saved file have many extrac nul characters to the end.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You should take a look at Spring's MultiPartFile support: http://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your while loop to:

```
while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);          
}
```

That because:

`write(byte[] b)` - Writes b.length bytes from the specified byte array to this output stream. So it will fill your outputstream with null to reach bytes size in the last while iteration.

`write(byte[] b, int off, int len)` - Writes len bytes from the specified byte array starting at offset off to this output stream

Hope this helps

Comment: Wow! Awesome! It worked. Thank you very much. You really are genius.